# Zend Framework 2 (ZF2) forwarding to a different module controller

Tags: php, frameworks, zend-framework2

I have a controller that processes a form. If posted data has certain value, I need to forward the user to a controller residing in a different module. I've tried this:

```
$post = $this->params()->fromPost();
if (!isset($post['terms'])) {
    $this->forward()->dispatch('Job\Controller\IndexController', 
        array('action' => 'index')); 
}
```

But the above code doesn't work. The documentation states that the controller has to be ServiceLocatorAware, but I don't know how to make the controller servicelocatoraware. Any idea how I can accomplish this?

Here is the error message from xdebug.

```
/home/test/mydomain/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:496
```

Message:

```
Zend\Mvc\Controller\ControllerManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Job\Controller\IndexController
```

Stack trace:

Comment: http://ctrl-f5.net/php/domain-layer-and-zendframework2-using-zendservicemanager/

Answer (score 1):

You've got an error because in the **ServiceLocator** your controller alias is

```
'Job\Controller\Index'
```

so you should use this controller path instead of 'Job\Controller\IndexController'

Answer (score 0):

try use header to redirect.

```
// $url is new target
header('Location:'.$url,1);
exit(0);
```

that's my redirect method, myabe you can use it:

```
public function Redirect($url,$withCurrentQueryString=true){
    if($withCurrentQueryString==true){
        if(strpos($url,'?')>0){
        $url=$url.'&'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    }
    else{
        $url=$url.'?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    }
    }
    header('Location:'.$url,1);
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: I need to pass posted parameters back to the view script, so redirect will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ServiceLocator Aware Interface in your controller:

```
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
```

Comment: How do I use this interface?  I made the controller implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface, but that didn't solve the problem.